# PHP explode string to tree array with unique string id

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php string as below :

```
$mystr ="f7_r11 f1_r2 f1_r19 f7_r10";
```

As you can see there is some ids stated with "f" these are top level , there is some ids stated with "r" these are sub level

I need explode it to an array include unique top level ( f ) contains  sub level ( r )
exactly like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [f_id] => 7
            [r_ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [r_id] => 11
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [r_id] => 10 
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [f_id] => 1
            [r_ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [r_id] => 2
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [r_id] => 19 
                        )

                )

        )


)
```

i tried some php code :

```
$explode = explode(" ", $mystr);
$unique = array_unique($explode);
$array= array_values($unique);
```

but final output is not that i want !! can anyone help me?

Comment: Explain very detailed how you would do that **manually** step by step. Then convert the given *algorithm* into code.

Comment: it will be easy if you have f7_r11_rxx f1_ryy_rzz, you can the split and have an easy mode to work on

Comment: @Marco Mura: there is no difference between your serialization and what OP has. You can convert between them in 3 lines.

Comment: @zerkms aren't however those 3 less line of code?

Comment: @Marco Mura: nope. 3 lines is to convert. The code to unserialize it back into the tree would be almost identical.

Comment: @zerkms i'd like too see an answer with that code, if is inerent with OP question

Comment: @Marco Mura: I'm not going to implement 2 algorithms for the OP for free (it won't help them in any way). But it's obvious that the formats are similar.

Comment: i found answer my self :)

Answer (score 0):

@Marco Mura @zerkms

i found answer my self :)

```
$explode = explode(" ", $array);

$fs=$fs2="";

for($i=0; $i<count($explode); $i++){
                    $f=strstr($explode[$i], '_', true);
                    $f = str_replace("f", "", $f);          
                    $fs[].=$f;
}

$fs = array_unique($fs);
$fs= array_values($fs);

for($i=0; $i<count($fs); $i++){
    $fs2[$i]['f_id']=$fs[$i];
}

for($i=0; $i<count($explode); $i++){
    $r=strstr($explode[$i], '_');
    $r = str_replace("_r", "", $r);
    $f=strstr($explode[$i], '_', true);
    $f = str_replace("f", "", $f);
    for($j=0; $j<count($fs); $j++){
        if( $f == $fs[$j]){
            $fs2[$j]['r_ids'][]=$r;
        }
    }
}

print_r($fs2);
```